# Javascript trouble with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, w2ui

I'm trying to create a simple GUI with the library w2ui. 
But I'm having an issue while adding a toolbar to my main layout. 
The toolbar is added before the layout is build.

I'm not very familiar with javascript callbacks as I am still learning.

Here is my javascript code :

```
function buildMainLayout(toolbar) {
    $(function () {
        var pstyle = 'background-color: #F5F6F7; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 5px;';
        $('#layout').w2layout({
            name: 'layout',
            panels: [
                { type: 'top',  size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'top', id: 'toolbar' },
                { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'left' },
                { type: 'main', style: pstyle, content: 'main' },
                { type: 'preview', size: '50%', resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'preview' },
                { type: 'right', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'right' },
                { type: 'bottom', size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'bottom' }
            ]
        });
    }, toolbar);
    $('#layout').height($( window ).height());
}

function buildMainToolbar(callback) {
    $().w2toolbar({
        name: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            { type: 'check',  id: 'item1', caption: 'Check', img: 'icon-page', checked: true },
            { type: 'break',  id: 'break0' },
            { type: 'menu',   id: 'item2', caption: 'Drop Down', img: 'icon-folder', items: [
                { text: 'Item 1', icon: 'icon-page' }, 
                { text: 'Item 2', icon: 'icon-page' }, 
                { text: 'Item 3', value: 'Item Three', icon: 'icon-page' }
            ]},
            { type: 'break', id: 'break1' },
            { type: 'radio',  id: 'item3',  group: '1', caption: 'Radio 1', icon: 'fa-star', checked: true },
            { type: 'radio',  id: 'item4',  group: '1', caption: 'Radio 2', icon: 'fa-star-empty' },
            { type: 'spacer' },
            { type: 'button',  id: 'item5',  caption: 'Item 5', icon: 'fa-home' }
        ]
    }, callback);
}

function addToolbar() {
    w2ui['layout'].content('top', w2ui['toolbar']);
}
```

Here is how I call it :

```
    buildMainLayout(buildMainToolbar(addToolbar));
```

I also made a jsfiddle for my problem :
https://jsfiddle.net/e1x1cg8j/5/

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the fiddle you need to load your libraries. Nothing is included.

Comment: You were right, sorry external ressources weren't saved

Answer (score 0):

I've search around but couldn't find any example using the callback as in your code.

I think that maybe you should use [onRender](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/common.onRender) option instead.

Something like this:

```
function buildMainLayout() {
    $(function () {
        var pstyle = 'background-color: #F5F6F7; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; padding: 5px;';
        $('#layout').w2layout({
            name: 'layout',
            panels: [
                { type: 'top',  size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'top', id: 'toolbar' },
                { type: 'left', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'left' },
                { type: 'main', style: pstyle, content: 'main' },
                { type: 'preview', size: '50%', resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'preview' },
                { type: 'right', size: 200, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'right' },
                { type: 'bottom', size: 50, resizable: true, style: pstyle, content: 'bottom' }
            ],
      onRender: buildMainToolbar
        });
    });
    $('#layout').height($( window ).height());
}

function buildMainToolbar() {
    $().w2toolbar({
        name: 'toolbar',
        items: [
            { type: 'check',  id: 'item1', caption: 'Check', img: 'icon-page', checked: true },
            { type: 'break',  id: 'break0' },
            { type: 'menu',   id: 'item2', caption: 'Drop Down', img: 'icon-folder', items: [
                { text: 'Item 1', icon: 'icon-page' }, 
                { text: 'Item 2', icon: 'icon-page' }, 
                { text: 'Item 3', value: 'Item Three', icon: 'icon-page' }
            ]},
            { type: 'break', id: 'break1' },
            { type: 'radio',  id: 'item3',  group: '1', caption: 'Radio 1', icon: 'fa-star', checked: true },
            { type: 'radio',  id: 'item4',  group: '1', caption: 'Radio 2', icon: 'fa-star-empty' },
            { type: 'spacer' },
            { type: 'button',  id: 'item5',  caption: 'Item 5', icon: 'fa-home' }
        ],
    onRender: addToolbar
    });
}

function addToolbar() {
    w2ui['layout'].content('top', w2ui['toolbar']);
}

buildMainLayout();
```

I'm not sure if this is the right event though.

Look into [this list of events](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/layout/events) available for the layout.

-------- EDIT ---------

Also check [into this](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/1.5/w2layout.assignToolbar)